# Как сделать обработчик ошибок в FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

```py
# on error
@app.exception_handler(HTTPException)
async def validation_exception_handler(exc: HTTPException, res: Response):
  res.status_code = exc.status_code
  return {'error': exc.detail}
```

Как сделать что то подобное?

Comment: Документацию смотрели? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/?h=erro#install-custom-exception-handlers